# How to make form invalid while checking for email availability?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to do async validation in reactive forms. I have a submit button that has to be disabled whenever I am giving some new input. But whenever I am giving the duplicate emails as input, it will search for availability by that time form will be valid for some time which makes the submit button clickable.

I want the submit button to be disabled while searching for availability.

```
validateEmailAvailability(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> => {
        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            take(1),
            switchMap(_ => this
                .checkEmailExists(control.value)
                .pipe(map(isExists => (isExists ? ({ isExists: true}) : null)))
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a combination of rxJs operators Tap and Finalize:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize

```
validateEmailAvailability(): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl):Observable<any> => {
            return control.valueChanges.pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                tap(() => this.disableSubmit = true),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                take(1),
                switchMap(_ => this.checkEmailExists(control.value)
                    .pipe(
                        map(isExists => (isExists ? ({ isExists: true}) : null)),
                        finalize(() => this.disableSumbit = false)
                    )),
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .....If we move that finalize() inside checkEmailExists pipe it will await until we receive a response from server.